# How to Search and Replace object property value if each key has an array of numbers? Javascript

Tags: javascript-objects

Let's say we have an object with an array of numbers for each property:

```js
const obj = {
    line1: [2, 13, 7, 6, 14],
    line2: [25, 16, 24, 27, 28],
    line3: [41, 31, 32, 44, 42],
  };
```

How can we Search for a specific number and Replace it with another number? 
Let's say we would like to find number 44 and replace it with 88? In a modern JS way...

Answer (score 0):

You can use loop to iterate on each key-value pair of the object, and then you can find and replace the number you want in the array. Keep in mind that if the number can be more than once in the same array you will have to loop on the array as well, otherwise you can use indexOf and assign the new value.

Here is an example:

```js
const obj = {
  line1: [2, 13, 7, 6, 14],
  line2: [25, 16, 24, 27, 28],
  line3: [41, 31, 32, 44, 42],
};

const changeNumber = (oldNum, newNum, obj) => {
  for (const [key, arr] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    const index = arr.indexOf(oldNum);
    if (index > -1) {
      arr[index] = newNum;
    }
  }
}
console.log(obj); // Before
changeNumber(44, 88, obj);
console.log(obj); // After

/* With duplicates entries */
const changeNumberDuplicate = (oldNum, newNum, obj) => {
  for (const [key, arr] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    let index = 0;
    do {
      index = arr.indexOf(oldNum, index);
      if (index > -1) {
        arr[index] = newNum;
      }
    } while (index > -1);
  }
}
const objDup = {
  line1: [2, 13, 44, 6, 44],
  line2: [44, 16, 44, 27, 28],
  line3: [41, 44, 32, 44, 42],
};
console.log(objDup); // Before
changeNumberDuplicate(44, 88, objDup);
console.log(objDup); // After
```

Comment: Thanks Zion, appreciated! I’m currently doing this with unique numbers, but you got me curious now. How would I loop through the array as well if there’s duplicates? Cheers.

Comment: @Learning-X , I guess you can use do...while loop and check with indexOf again, and to keep it more efficient, start the indexOf from the last index found. I edited the answer with another function for duplicates